# Storing numbers project in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, numbers, int, storage

Check the [website](http://themrmiller.com/program/projects/temperatureReadings.php) for example and reqiurements.

This is what I have so far:

```
        private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        textBox1.Clear();
        input++;
        MessageBox.Show(input.ToString());

    }        
}
```

Comment: So.. what's the problem?

Comment: I dont know how to count the number of numbers entered. In the example, it counts how many numbers you typed in and opens in a message box when you close the second form

Comment: You need to specify what your problem is and what assistance you're looking for.

Comment: So if my guess is right, you have several NumericUpDown controls in Form2, and once you close Form2 you want those to be transferred to Form1?

Comment: no i need just a small part of it, don't know how to count total numbers entered in the textbox

Comment: Come on dude, go easy on him. It's clear he's new to programming and StackOverflow. He'll learn the proper way to ask a question eventually.

Comment: I tried to improve my code. I don't know how to press the button and make my textbox clear so i can enter more numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this looks like homework, I'll just give you instructions. You won't learn otherwise.

```
1 - On Form1, once the button to open Form2 is clicked, make sure you do Form1.Hide() or Form1.Visible = false, and ppen Form2.

2 - In Form2 there is a textbox and a button.

3 - Once that button is clicked, get the text of the textbox, and split it by "space" to get an array of numbers, MyArray.

4 - Finally, display a MessageBox containing MyArray.Length;

5 - Form2.Hide(), Form1.Show()
```

Oh, and I failed to mention that Form1 and Form2 should be static.

This is what OP is looking for, right?

Comment: whats spliting it by space mean?

Comment: string[] MyArray = "Word1 Word2 Word3".Split(null);

Comment: Is this counting how many digits i have in a number, cause that's not what i need. For example if i enter 100 100 and 100, it will say i have 3 numbers total.

Comment: Yup, that's it. It counts the amount of words.. or numbers in this case in a string.

Comment: I tried the code and it works but i have to save the numbers. For example when i enter 100 i have to press submit. And then when i close out the form, it shows a messagebox say in have 1 number

Comment: Add a integer in Form2, and each time you press submit (and the textbox IS NOT empty) increase the integer by 1.

Comment: how do you make the text box clear when ever I hit the submit

Comment: MyTextbox.Clear(); or MyTextbox.Text = ""; or MyTextbox.Text = String.Empty; Go with the first choice.

Comment: Thank you, but my code is still wrong. I just added from 0 and not from the textbox so it will always be one. How do i change this so it will add what i put in the textbox.

Comment: Okay here: You put 3 numbers in the textbox: "123 456 789". Then you split the numbers like I told you before, you get an array of 3 strings. You then add the global integer +3. You DO NOT global integer = 3. That would erase previous number counts.

Comment: I want to put the numbers seperately, like i enter 123, then press submit and the textbox would clear so i can enter my second number.

Comment: You're making this hard on yourself.
You need 2 buttons. One button when clicked will clear the textbox, and do Input++;
The other button will display Input via MessageBox.

Comment: sadly i can only have one button, is it possible to close a form and make a message box show up?

Comment: Looking at your requirements, it doesn't indicate you must have one button.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should probably ask your teacher for assistance. He's probably a nice guy, and I'm sure he was walking around the classroom today looking for students to help. I'm sure your teacher may have even set up a classroom forum, maybe using a website such as [Piazza](https://piazza.com/), where you can ask your classmates for help, which may be of more use to use since your classmates will have a better context for this project. People here are willing to help, but when you haven't even learned about arrays yet some of their help may not be useful.

That being said, it looks like you already have the code to store the count of the numbers entered. Your input variable should be declared at the top of the class, you increment it in the button, and display it in the MessageBox. The MessageBox, though, should display when the form is closed so make sure that part is in the FormClosing event handler.

I hope that helps, Darian.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just make a global variable that increments every time a number is entered?

Comment: i tried stating {int input = 0;} and then in the button{ textBox1.Text = input++;    MessageBox.Show(input.ToString()); }

Comment: Input is the global variable, right? Then you do Input += MyArrayOfNumbers.Length; The += means Input = Input + X. As for the array, it's an array of strings you get from splitting the original.

Comment: The Input variable has to be inside Form2 not inside the button click method.

Comment: Are you going to let the user enter info like this:

Comment: To enter 3 inputs of 100 will the user just type 100 3 times with spaces and then click button1 (assuming that's your submit button not closing button) or 100 then click button1 3 times? If it's the first then you're going to need to count how many numbers are in each input (use something like this: yourInputString.Split(" ").Count) and then add that to your global counter (or set if you're only trying to get the last number of inputs taken). If not then you'll just ++ your global counter every time the user clicks button1 and then display if the user closes out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get how much number the user had entered.For Eg:- if user enters 100 50 90.
Then simply put the content of the text box to an array (the spacing is mustly needed.)
Then declare a global variable 
    int count=0;
Then in a for loop.
`for(int i=0;i<length_of_array;i++)
        {
        if(your_array[i]==' ')
        count++;
        }
    MessageBox.Show("There are "+count+" numbers");`

Thats all !!!